# Setup command line completion with yargs

Tags: node.js, command-line-arguments, yargs

I'm creating a script with node JS and want to enable async command line completion with [yargs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs).

The [completion section of the yargs documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs#completion-cmd-description-fn) says: *"concat the generated script to your .bashrc or .bash_profile"*

But I don't see any information about how to generate the script.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs#completion-cmd-description-fn) isn't completely clear how to do this, but I figured it out.

Install yargs

```
npm install -g yargs
```

Create your script (e.g *script.js*)

```
#! /usr/local/bin/node
var argv = require('yargs')
    .completion('completion', function(current, argv, done) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          done([
            'apple',
            'banana'
          ]);
        }, 500);
    })
    .argv;
```

Save your script and set permissions

```
chmod +x script.js
```

On the command line pass the command name  (the first parameter in the completion call) to your script as the first parameter.

```
./script.js completion
```

This will output the command line completion block to add to *.bashrc or .bash_profile*

```
_yargs_completions()
{
    local cur_word args type_list

    cur_word="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
    args=$(printf "%s " "${COMP_WORDS[@]}")

    # ask yargs to generate completions.
    type_list=`./shan.js --get-yargs-completions $args`

    COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${type_list}" -- ${cur_word}) )

    # if no match was found, fall back to filename completion
    if [ ${#COMPREPLY[@]} -eq 0 ]; then
      COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -f -- "${cur_word}" ) )
    fi

    return 0
}
```

Comment: In case someone needs more information, there is additional documentation here : https://yargs.js.org/docs/#api-reference-completioncmd-description-fn